# Why are there a line of dots instead of a box plot using geom_boxplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have been trying to plot relative abundance of specific phyla in 4 different groups.

I'm not sure why, but when I plot my boxplot with jitter, I get a line of dots in the middle instead of a box plot.

[image]

My code to plot the image is this:

```
my_plot <- my_data %>%
ggplot(aes(x=group, y=rel_abund, color=group) +
geom_boxplot() +
geom_jitter(size=0.4, alpha=0.9) +
facet_wrap(~taxon, nrow=1, scales = "free_y") +
ylab("Relative Abundance") +
xlab("Group") + 
theme(text=element_text(family="Times"),legend.position = "none")
```

Data:

```
structure(list(group = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), 
    rel_abund = c(0.0224489795918367, 0.0510204081632653, 0.00816326530612245, 
    0.0714285714285714, 0.0489795918367347, 0.036734693877551, 
    0.00204081632653061, 0.0102040816326531, 0.0142857142857143, 
    0.00408163265306122, 0.00816326530612245, 0, 0, 0.00408163265306122, 
    0, 0.00408163265306122, 0.00204081632653061, 0.00204081632653061, 
    0, 0.00204081632653061), level = c("phylum", "phylum", "phylum", 
    "phylum", "phylum", "phylum", "phylum", "phylum", "phylum", 
    "phylum", "phylum", "phylum", "phylum", "phylum", "phylum", 
    "phylum", "phylum", "phylum", "phylum", "phylum"), taxon = c("Firmicutes", 
    "Actinobacteriota", "Firmicutes", "Firmicutes", "Proteobacteria", 
    "Firmicutes", "Proteobacteria", "Actinobacteriota", "Proteobacteria", 
    "Firmicutes", "Proteobacteria", "Firmicutes", "Proteobacteria", 
    "Firmicutes", "Actinobacteriota", "Actinobacteriota", "Firmicutes", 
    "Bacteroidota", "Actinobacteriota", "Firmicutes")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `geom_jitter()` is a shortcut for `geom_point()` with jittered position.  Your points are plotting over the box plot is my guess.  Comment out the `geom_jitter()` line and see if there is a box plot there.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72411387/edit) with the output of `dput(my_data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(my_data, 20))`. Also, try `alpha = 0.3` and see if the box plot shows up beneath the points. But please post data, I don't understand why the plot has points of two different sizes.

Comment: As already mentioned, your points are probably hiding your boxplot. Note that ggplot2 draws its geoms in order, if your code has a geom_jitter before a geom_boxplot, it will produce a different plot than the reverse order.

Comment: @RuiBarradas the big dots are the box plot’s outliers.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Removing geom_jitter() did not show a box plot, instead it removed the smaller dots on my graph and kept the line of dots in the middle

Comment: @RuiBarradas I used 7 instead of 20 to be able to fit my answer here: structure(list(Group = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), 
    rel_abund = c(0.0224489795918367, 0.0510204081632653, 0.00816326530612245, 
    0.0714285714285714, 0.0489795918367347, 0.036734693877551, 
    0.00204081632653061), level = c("phylum", "phylum", "phylum", 
    "phylum", "phylum", "phylum", "phylum"), taxon = c("Firmicutes", 
    "Actinobacteriota", "Firmicutes", "Firmicutes", "Proteobacteria", 
    "Firmicutes", "Proteobacteria")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: You should have posted the data *in the question*, where there's enough room for 20 rows. I cannot reproduce the problem but there are some inconsistencies/errors in the posted code. 1) R is case sensitive and in the data it's `Group`, in the code `group`; 2) the `color` aesthetic is not mapped to a variable, all points are black. As for the box-and-whiskers plots, they are plotted without problems.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Sorry about that. I've updated my question. Hopefully that makes it more clear.

Comment: Try removing `color = group` from the initial call to `ggplot` and put it in `geom_jitter(aes(color = group), etc)` instead. In your code it's the color for all layers but if it's only in `geom_jitter`, only the points have colors.